# Why does QDBus complains about wrong type?

Tags: qt, dbus

What's wrong with the following snippet?
I am constantly getting the error

`Unexpected reply signature: got "a{sa{sv}}", expected "" (QMap<QString,QVariantMap>)`

```
QDBusInterface connIface(
                    NM_DBUS_SERVICE,
                    "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1",
                    NM_DBUS_INTERFACE_SETTINGS_CONNECTION,
                    QDBusConnection::systemBus());

QDBusReply<QMap<QString, QMap<QString, QVariant>> > settingsResult = connIface.call("GetSettings");
```

I really don't get it, seems to be perfectly fine to me. Is it possible that this has to do with the compiler / header-versions somehow?

Comment: the different formats for got and expected are odd, I guess that's where the problem lies somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to register the expected Response first!

In my case it was like

```
#include <QtDBus/QDBusMetaType>
// ...
typedef QMap<QString, QMap<QString, QVariant> > ConnectionDetails;
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ConnectionDetails)
```

and

```
int main() {
    qDBusRegisterMetaType<ConnectionDetails>();
    // ...
}
```